# Getting Started with Network Programming - PlayBook

Tags: c++, c, networking, blackberry, blackberry-playbook

I was just a bit bored and was thinking that it would be cool to make an application for my to access files on a work group network from a mobile device.

The thing is, I have no idea where to start. I am fairly well versed with programming in C/C++. I was wondering if there were any API's that would make my grunt a lot less?

I am trying to make an app for the BlackBerry PlayBook, just fyi.

Any suggestions for a starting point would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. Blackberry's website has all the tools you need to start developing for the PlayBook. For C/C++ development, you can check out: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/documentation

QNX (the OS on the PlayBook) is a powerful RTOS and something I'd consider buying a PlayBook for, just to play around and develop on.

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry developers site is a good place to start IMO:
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/devzone/

And for native apps (C/C++):
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/